# Python отказывается имитировать события клавиатуры!

Tags: python

Написал простой скрипт на Python, который открывает программу "выполнить" и пишет в нее что то.

Он отлично работает, когда у него расширение `.py`, но когда я компилирую его при помощи `pyinstaller` в `.exe` файл, то он не хочет нажимать ту самую клавишу <kbd>Win</kbd> из комбинации <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, скрипт нажимает только на цифры и буквы, может в Windows запрещено `.exe` файлам такое делать? Не знаю..

```
import pyautogui
import time
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'r')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('p')
pyautogui.press('r')
pyautogui.press('i')
pyautogui.press('d')
pyautogui.press('u')
pyautogui.press('r')
pyautogui.press('o')
pyautogui.press('k')
```

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается антивирус 360 total security блокирует python файл,не зря у него прозвище "параноик"